# Case of side notes?

Tags: capitalization

When writing a book, some authors put important short terms they use in the main text also into the margin near the usage position. Assuming that these marginal notes in your book are always short and never constitute full sentences, what's more appropriate: capitalize the first letter of a marginal note or leave it small (assuming it's not a proper noun)?  Why?  In this respect, do the variants of English (AmE, BrE, CanE, AuE) or publishers' styles differ?

Comment: I'm not sure that this really is an English language learning question as we usually think of it.  This seems more like a matter of individual publishers' style guides.

Comment: @stangdon Despite searching, I have not found any evidence for this supposition of yours regarding the publishers' style guides. Hence the question; the public here might  (or might not) know better than Google.

Comment: It is a very niche usage.  You say  "some authors put important short terms they use in the main text also into the margin"  So I assume you have seen an example of this.  Follow that example (and also tell us about it, because I've never seen such a style) I doubt that there is enough examples to make any kind of generalisations about dialect or explain "why".

Comment: @JamesK In the examples I saw, the author put certain term into the margin and their explanation into the glossary, accompanied by the page list for each term. All somewhat suitable examples of English books I personally saw were bad: there, the author was not consistent on the capitalization and it didn't even occur to him.

Comment: That's probably as much as you are going to get.  This isn't a common thing to do.  If you are going to do it, be consistent.  I'd suggest using small caps.

Comment: @JamesK A consistent German example is https://www.belleslettres.eu/buch/leseprobe-deutsch-fur-dichter-und-denker.pdf#page=25 (“magedīn” on page 23). Of course, you cannot transfer German customs to English typography. Small caps are, unfortunately, a no-go for me because they are used for something else.

Comment: These kinds of decisions are made by the book designer, the same person(s) who chooses the font, margin width, and so on. This person might or might not be required to adhere to a set of standards kept by the publisher. If a book has a complicated layout, like a textbook, the book designer will work closely with the author. If the book is simple, like a typical novel, the designer might never interact with the author. Even if there is some interaction with the author, the final decisions might be made by the designer and the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very minor usage case, I can't say I've ever seen keywords put into marginal notes. How you present these is pretty much up to you. Just be consistent.